# How do I transfer data from userData in JSON format to a pie chart? ASP.Net Core

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-core, charts

I cannot make a json format from the database suitable for pie chart.

How can i take userData in JSON?

```
originalFormData[0]= ""[{\"type\":\"radio-group\",\"label\":\"Radio Group\",\"name\":\"radio-group-1563437970472\",\"values\":[{\"label\":\"Option 1\",\"value\":\"option-1\"},{\"label\":\"Option 2\",\"value\":\"option-2\"},{\"label\":\"Option 3\",\"value\":\"option-3\"}],\"userData\":[\"option-1\"]}]""

originalFormData[1]= ""[{\"type\":\"radio-group\",\"label\":\"Radio Group\",\"name\":\"radio-group-1563437970472\",\"values\":[{\"label\":\"Option 1\",\"value\":\"option-1\"},{\"label\":\"Option 2\",\"value\":\"option-2\"},{\"label\":\"Option 3\",\"value\":\"option-3\"}],\"userData\":[\"option-2\"]}]""
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want to take the data of `userData` key from JSON ?

Comment: Yes, i mean it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a JSON parser, like [JSON.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) , parse the array first

```
 string json = "[{\"type\":\"radio-group\",\"label\":\"Radio Group\",\"name\":\"radio-group-1563437970472\",\"values\":[{\"label\":\"Option 1\",\"value\":\"option-1\"},{\"label\":\"Option 2\",\"value\":\"option-2\"},{\"label\":\"Option 3\",\"value\":\"option-3\"}],\"userData\":[\"option-1\"]}]";

        JArray parsedArray = JArray.Parse(json);
        foreach (JObject parsedObject in parsedArray.Children<JObject>())
        {
            foreach (JProperty parsedProperty in parsedObject.Properties())
            {
                string propertyName = parsedProperty.Name;
                if (propertyName.Equals("userData"))
                {
                    Array propertyValue = parsedProperty.Value.ToArray();

                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can take userdata in string and then parse it like this JSON.parse('{ "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}') it will convert string in jSON

Comment: How do I write this code properly?

`$.parseJSON($.parseJSON(originalFormData[0]))[0].userData` -> ["option-1"]